# How to check if a cognito access token has expired?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

The access token is valid for 1 hour.
I know how to use a refresh token to update an access token.
However, I don't know how to check if the cognito access token has expired.

Pattern1: Measure the time since token authentication by timer thread.
-> Waste of CPU resources...

Pattern2: Record the authentication time & Compare current time.

Pattern3: Check using the AWS SDK.
-> How to use?

Pattern4: other way.

What is the best way?

```
if ({ m_access_token is expired? })
{
    Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Model::InitiateAuthRequest request;
    request.SetAuthFlow(Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Model::AuthFlowType::REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH);
    request.SetClientId(m_client_id);
    request.AddAuthParameters("USERNAME", m_user_name);
    request.AddAuthParameters("REFRESH_TOKEN", m_refresh_token);
    auto outcome = m_cognito_identity_provider_client->InitiateAuth(request);
    if (outcome.IsSuccess())
    {
        m_access_token = outcome.GetResult().GetAuthenticationResult().GetAccessToken();
    }
}
```

- AWS SDK for C++
- Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Doesn't the SDK automatically refresh tokens for you?

Comment: No, it doesn't refresh. I chose to save the access token in the member variable, so it doesn't update automatically. I looked at the source code this link. https://gist.github.com/manishpin/f7d8e9af84068bd9b0220bb2c7d14a4d I get the access token by "challenge_request.GetResult().GetAuthtiencationResult().GetAccessToken()".

Comment: Best approach would be not bothering when access token expires. Just have a try catch method where if you get the expired error call the refresh token api and get new access token and store it.

Comment: That is a good idea. I will try using try-catch.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I choose retrying by try-catch.

Because, If I use the timestamp, I should to use retrying for fail safe in the end.

thanks.